# Serial can receive but cant send

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, serial-port

I recently installed Ubuntu20.4 as a dual boot with Debian both using plasma-desktop. On an old Samsung laptop with a series 1 i5.

```
enter code here
```

I'm trying to talk to the REPL of an `esp32` board with `micropython`.
No problem on the Debian boot but when I boot Ubuntu and run `cu`, or `minicomm` or other serial coms, I can see the esp32 output but nothing I type gets sent or echoed. If I push the boot button on esp I see the output and get a `>>>` prompt but that's it.

I'm no Linux expert, but everything looks to set the same in both boots.
File permission & user groups identical.
`stty -a -F /dev/ttyUSB0` - returns the same on both boots.
Nothing shows up in `journalctl -f` when I try to communicate. Or in `dmesg`.

I had some problems with the display manager when plasma installed. `Sddm` seemed to turn off my video card so I went back to `gdm3`. Otherwise, everything else seems to work.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: PS- I can flash the esp32 (in boot mode) ok using esptool so serial seems to work both ways then

Answer (score 1):

I finally found that everytime I run cu or screen or minicom the hardware flow control, crtscts, gets switched on. If I turn off flow control while the session is running, I get to send again. I just need to find how to make it permanent.

Comment: [link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/209663) **Here,** I found the answer